# Software to convert video to picture or video to .JPG to avoid taking screenshots by hand for many videos

Tags: software-recommendation, video, convert

I want an application to convert videos to a series of images.

- I need to be able to do conversion from videos to `.jpg` and `.png` and other picture format output files.
- I need to be able to set the number of frames used for conversion
- I need to be able to specify the quality of the output images
- I need to be able to make on-the-fly adjustments.

Is there anything that will work out of the box to do what I need?

Answer (score 4):

The command line tool ffmpeg can disassemble a video in individual image files, and also can reassemble image files into a video. ffmpeg has a myriad of options allowing for a very high level of control, but that comes at a price of complexity and some learning curve.

For example, the following command will output an image every second:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1 out%d.png`

The extension you provide, determines the file format you export. You can, if needed, provide extra options to control the graphical output yourself (i.e. change compression level, resolution, etc.)

Resulting images may then be further batch processed using Imagemagicks `convert`. For batch processing, you may prefer to use `mogrify`, which overwrites the original image file.

Comment: Yes and No when I was running Win 7 Pro, I had a program that did all this for me, it was a watermarking program that would let me make all the adjustments like how sharp, bright, anything I Needed, and chose the format, and where to save. A 1gig file took about 10 min to process. With what your suggesting a 1gig file takes about a week to break down into files I then have to adjust every single file separately making what was a 10min job into 100's of hours or more of work. And its almost impossible to do anything else on the computer while that 1gig file is being broken down in singles. TKS

Comment: Batch process the resulting files with `convert` or `mogrify`. It will still take you less than 10 minutes. I added this to the answer. Linux is modular: use different dedicated tools to achieve your job. It may take some time to build the commands, but once done, you start such operation in a fraction of a second, and it runs fully authomatic.